# Stuck in the algorithm for formation of B-tree, what is the exact algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I'm learning B-trees from [this site](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/djimenez/utsa/cs3343/lecture17.html). In the topic of insertion of data in B-trees, as given in site, I used this data to construct the binary tree: `5 9 3 7 1 2 8 6 0 4`. Upto step 9 I can understand the insertion process, but in step 10, why can't we insert `4` in the regular manner?

It says, we have to check for further insertions also. So when and how to assure that the further insertion will work perfectly. What is the exact algorithm for this?

Answer (score 1):

The description for step 10 says "It would be nice to just stick 4 in with 3, but the B-Tree algorithm requires us to split the full root". This is of course total nonsense.

The B-tree algorithm requires no such thing, but some simplified algorithms - like the one used by the page's authors - demand that certain unnecessary splits and merges be performed so that they can get away with a partial implementation of the full B-tree algorithm.

In particular, when a node at a lower level is split then this can cause further splits higher up in the tree, because each split pushes a separator key upwards. In extremis *every* level above the split node could split as well, up to - and including - the root.

Handling this efficiently has implications on locking, and it requires remembering the path taken during the initial descent from the root to the node where the insertion/split is to occur.

On one hand this means that simple recursive function calls no longer work, because it is usually not possible to walk the call stack upwards. It also means that the whole path from the root to the insertion target node needs to be locked in a concurrent situation (for naive implementations), or at least the sub path from the lowest parent that might split down to the target node.

The simple cop-out works by performing additional restructurings on the way down to ensure that changes further down in the tree **cannot** bubble upwards. These restructurings are unnecessary from a B-tree perspective but necessary for the integrity of the simplified strategy.

During the descent for an *insert* op, all full nodes encountered on the way down need to be split. During the descent for a *delete* op, all nodes that cannot donate at least one key need to be merged. And yes, this means that certain sequences of inserts and deletes can cause heavy unnecessary restructurings of the tree for each and every single operation, nullifying the principal advantage of the B-tree scheme (amortisation of the structural management cost).